# Retrieving User Profile Information in Auth0

Tags: angular, typescript, observable, auth0

I’m developing an Angular 8 SPA and have successfully integrated Auth0 authentication. The profile information for each user displays just as the Auth0 tutorial shows. See the screen output below. How do I access the email property after the user logs in?

```
{
  "nickname": "user,
  "name": "user@email.com",
  "picture": "https://s.gravatar.com/user_image.png",
  "updated_at": "2020-01-15T17:39:10.467Z",
  "email": "user@email.com",
  "email_verified": true,
  "sub": "auth0|000000000000000000000000"
}
```

In app.module.ts, I tried subscribing with the following:

```
currentUser: string;
this.auth.userProfile$.subscribe(userProfile => {this.currentUser = userProfile});
console.log(this.currentUser);
```

However, in the console I just get: `null`. As far as I can tell, **auth.service.ts** provides the necessary observable:

```
private userProfileSubject$ = new BehaviorSubject<any>(null);
userProfile$ = this.userProfileSubject$.asObservable();
```

Any direction is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your `console.log(this.currentUser)` is getting executed before the value is emitted to your subscription.

If you change your code as follows, it should work:

```
this.auth.userProfile$.subscribe(userProfile => {
    this.currentUser = userProfile;
    console.log(this.currentUser);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

i don't know why are you subscribing in `app.module.ts` since the `auth.service.ts` gives the possibility to connect in any other component.

i try the tutorial from the Auth0 [official page](https://github.com/auth0-samples/auth0-angular-samples/tree/master/01-Login) and modify `home-content.component.ts` adding

```
// import section
import { AuthService } from 'src/app/auth/auth.service';

getSessionScope(){
    this.auth.userProfile$.subscribe(data => this.currentUser = data);
    console.log(this.currentUser);

  }
```

and in `home-content.component.html` adding

```
<button
      id="testButton"
      class="btn btn-primary btn-margin"
      (click)="getSessionScope()"
    >
      log session
    </button>
```

and once the click event is trigger through the auth.service you can get the session data. so if you need the email the try `this.currentUser.email`